# How do i Connect the back end of a website to the front end using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, backend, web-frontend

I am currently helping to fix some problems on a website. One of the plugins seems to not work (Magic Fields) I just got assigned the task to help connect the front end and back end of this website using PHP however; I have no idea how to connect front end and back end and the Magic Fields plugin is not working. On the Live website there is no issue with magic fields just on the version we are trying to make changes to.

I have tried to study up on plugins and magic fields since starting this task however i don't truly understand how to interact with plugins on wordpress. I have not used it very much. My best guess is that the PHP we are currently using isn't the correct PHP for the plugin.

I expect to be able to get the website up and running with the plugins we currently have and to learn how to use PHP to connect the front end and back end.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is a bit vague. F.e.: What is "backend" in your understanding? (in mine php _is_ backend) _"seems to not work "_ means what exactly? We cannot really help without 1st an exact error description and 2nd some sample code.

Comment: by "backend" im talking server side so plug ins and php but im considering php slightly different because it is used to connect plugins to frontend code. Currently there is no error but the website is not working how it should or how it is on the live website.